# Как создать Java generic класс, который принимает только Number или String и ничего более

Tags: java, классы, generics, classloader

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли создать  Java generic класс, который принимает только Number или String и ничего более. Если указывать тип отличный от Number или String была ошибка компиляции?

Comment: ошибка во время выполнения программы или анализа налету?

Comment: зачем вам это нужно? опишите исходную задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Можно скрыть конструктор и использовать фактори метод. 
Таким образом можно инициализирвоать только определенные

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> {

    // скрываем конструктор. Доступен только для фактори методов. 
    private MyGenericClass(T value) {
        // implement the constructor
    }


    public static MyGenericClass<Long> newInstance(Long value) {
        return new MyGenericClass<Long>(value);
    }

    public static MyGenericClass<Integer> newInstance(Integer value) {
        return new MyGenericClass<Integer>(value);
    }

    public static MyGenericClass<String> newInstance(String value) {
        return new MyGenericClass<String>(value);
    }

}



MyGenericClass<Integer> integerMyGenericClass = MyGenericClass.newInstance(123);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как написать `<T extends String|Number>` не выйдет, можно использовать такой вариант:

```
class A<T> {
    public A(T t) {
        if (!(t instanceof String || t instanceof Number)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```